# Style is only applied to first element block

Tags: php, html, css

I am currently working to a rating functionality with PHP. The radio inputs are working fine, it checks wherever I hover my cursor it radio inputs. But I have noticed that the color is only applied to the first group of radio inputs.

Here is my sample PHP Code,

```
$auditor_count = 1;

$auditors = array($_GET['auditor1'], $_GET['auditor2'], $_GET['auditor3'], $_GET['auditor4']);

foreach($auditors as $auditor) {
   if($auditor == "") continue;
?>
<div class="form-group ms-5 d-flex justify-content-between">
     <p><small><?=$auditor?></small></p>
     <div class="rating rating__<?=$auditor_count?> ms-2">
          <input id="rating-5" class="rating-input" type="radio" name="rating-<?=$auditor_count?>" value="5"/><label for="rating-5"><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></label>
          <input id="rating-4" class="rating-input" type="radio" name="rating-<?=$auditor_count?>" value="4"/><label for="rating-4"><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></label>
           <input id="rating-3" class="rating-input" type="radio" name="rating-<?=$auditor_count?>" value="3"/><label for="rating-3"><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></label>
           <input id="rating-2" class="rating-input" type="radio" name="rating-<?=$auditor_count?>" value="2"/><label for="rating-2"><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></label>
           <input id="rating-1" class="rating-input" type="radio" name="rating-<?=$auditor_count?>" value="1" checked/><label for="rating-1"><i class="fa-solid fa-star"></i></label>
         </div>
    </div>
<?php $auditor_count++; } ?>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
<style>
.rating {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    color: #ddd;
}
.rating input {
    display: none;
}
.rating label:hover,
.rating label:hover ~ label,
.rating input:checked + label,
.rating input:checked + label ~ label {
    color: #ffc107;
}
</style>
```

By the way, I copied this frontend somewhere in the internet. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this,

```
<style>
.rating {
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    color: #ddd;
    position: relative;
}
.rating input {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.rating label {
    pointer-events: none;
}
.rating label:hover,
.rating label:hover ~ label,
.rating input:checked + label,
.rating input:checked + label ~ label {
    color: #ffc107;
}
</style>
```